# Custom events programming in Node.js: I/O bound event-oriented design patterns?

Tags: node.js, events, io, event-handling, event-driven-design

I'm developing a factory automation software (a totem vehicle gate) in node.js.

The program has manage a bunch of 'tasks', by example it has to:

- monitor and control some I/O digital signals
- manage messages from external hosts, say via TCP socket messages
- poll other devices via HTTP REST (I need to convert a polling into an event)
- interface with a user though a keypad (and a screen terminal / voice output)
- query a relational DB, on an external server
- etc.

It's common sense that node.js is a perfect environment to manage (I/O) events and I'm aware about the fact I can generate custom events with  `EventEmitter` class.

Let assume that, for all tasks above detailed:

- any task could be managed in asynchronous way (HTTP/TCP/keyboard),
- I'm able to manage all above 'tasks' within a Node.js single thread (1 CPU core)

So I could design my main program as event-driven, implementing application logics as callbacks to SW events (Node.js customs events) mapping these with I/O (HW) events.

Here below a pseudocode:

```js
// -----------------------------
// module A: keyboard management
// -----------------------------

// when user enter 5 digits (code) on the keypad keystroke (code omitted), 
// emit the SW event 'digitsEntered'

keyBoardDialog.emit('digitsEntered', code)

// ----------------------------------------
// module B: I/O digital signals management
// ----------------------------------------

// poll (every ~300 msecs) through HTTP GET 
// to get a buffer containing all digital input bits
// and when the digital input 1 goes ON, emit SW event, 'DI1ON' (code omitted)

digitalInputs.emit('DI1ON')


// -----------
// main module
// -----------

// all events handler
keyBoardDialog.on ('digitsEntered', (code) => doActionWithDigits(code) )
digitalInputs.on ('DI1ON', doAnotherAction() )

function doActionWithDigits(code) {
  writeOnDatabase(code) // asynch
  writeDigitalOutput(4) // HTTP GET = asynch
  // any other synch or asynch function
}
```

Custom events callbacks (handlers), could contain sequential and/or asyncronous (asynch) functions.

By example let's focus on the task to read keystrokes from a keyboard.
The user has to input 5 digits and the keyboard module logic triggers the custom event (`'digitsEntered'`).

The `doActionWithDigits()` handler contains async functions.
Here possible timing/ data-sharing issues arise.

Because the event-based, but single thread architecture, I have to manage sort of 'no interrupt' logic inside the custom e event handler. To avoid data R/W overlap. To avoid that custom event is triggered again when running, etc. etc.

It seems to me that I'm facing classical multi thread management nightmares.

My questions:

- There is any good practice / guideline about how to manage custom events handlers in similar scenarios?
- What's the real advantage to use custom events, instead of Node.js callbacks?
  It's all in all a matter of decoupling logic?
- May you suggest something to read (articles/books) about design patterns good practices?

Comment: From what I understand from your use case I don't see anything wrong with going with one or more custom event emitters.

As a generic advice, start simple and see where that leads you. If you will need to re-organize your code or revisit your approach because of new complexity you can always do that later.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks Luciano, I updated the question, trying to explain better